# Does VLC media player have a C# interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, vlc

Is it possible to read the track statistics(time, title etc) from a currently playing file in VLC play using a wrapper in a C# console application? does anyone have any recommendations for a wrapper to use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is

- a [.NET Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC) which is

  > a .Net user control that uses libvlc interfaces
- [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/) which is

  > a .net library that hosts the audio/video capabilities of the VLC libraries. In other words, it's a .net wrapper around `libvlc`.
- an implementation on CodePlex - [DMediaPlayer - Simple VLC frontend.](http://dmediaplayer.codeplex.com/) which is

  > a simple but nice frontend for VLC media player.

Answer (score 15):

Also there is [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/)

The project have all you need and it is compatible all versions of VLC >= 1.1

You can find samples on site.