# C# Vlc.DotNet Libraries - Null reference exception

Tags: c#, vlc

Recently stumbled upon this post whilst trying to decide on the best way of getting a VLC player into C#.

[Does VLC media player have a C# interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382793/does-vlc-media-player-have-a-c-sharp-interface)

I downloaded the dll files and imported them into my project, but then realised I had no real idea of how to use them.  Has anyone got a Windows Forms example of this code that works?  The code have tried is shown below -

```
Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.MediaBase media = new
    Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(@"C:\Users\...\SampleVideos\Wildlife.wmv");

Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl vlcControl1 = new Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl();
vlcControl1.Play(media);
```

I am also using the code in this link in the main program.cs of my project.

http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Forms

The current problem I experience is that upon starting the project it throws a NullReferenceException when it gets to ->

```
vlcControl1.Play(media)
```

The problem seems to be with the vlcControl but I am unsure why.  The documentation seems to rather thin and I couldn't find any working examples on the codeplex site.  If anyone has a working forms example or knows what I might have missed please let me know!

Here is the call stack present when the error occurs ->

```
RTSPViewer_Test.exe!RTSPViewer_Test.Form1.Form1_Load(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e) Line 31 + 0xd bytes C#
RTSPViewer_Test.exe!RTSPViewer_Test.Program.Main() Line 30 + 0x1d bytes C#
```

When debugging it appears that the Media and Medias attribute of the VLC control are both null.  When trying to set the Media of the control to the media object created above a

```
NullReferenceException
```

Checking the VLC control object Media does indeed equal null, but I am not sure why it hasn't been initialised properly.

Comment: Any chance you could include the call stack for the NullReferenceException? Given the code above, neither vlcControl1 or media could be null, so the exception must be coming from logic inside the Play method.

Comment: Check this out

http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Presentation%20of%20Vlc.DotNet%20alpha%202

Comment: I'll add the call stack  info later today, I think it might be something within the function call myself.  @Raj, that example was written for an older version of the DLL's and much of the code no longer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was unable to get the program to work using the latest version of the Vlc.dotnet libraries but instead used the alpha 2 version which was posted by Raj.  I used VLC version 1.1.5 with this library to get the basic example to function properly.  My end objective was to stream from an rtsp device, however this library does not appear to support this functionality yet.

For anyone looking to use a good C# wrapper for using VLC then this is a great example -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC

Used the library files from VLC 1.1.1 with this project and works fine.  Supports pretty much all the features that you would usually use in VLC but gives you much more control over what you use them for.

Many of the issues that arise when using these DLL wrappers arose from incorrect versions of the source DLL files.  The VLC libraries are only 32 bit at this time, so you need to make sure to compile using x86 mode otherwise the libvlc.dll will not load properly and the application will crash.  Using the above example you must also make sure that the libvlc.dll, libvlccore.dll and the plugins folder are included in the build folder.