# Video player in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video

What is the best way to make a video player using C# so that we can take the required snapshot by using button.

Comment: This is not a real question. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Very broad question, There is plenty of 3rd party applications/librarys that can do this, or is there a specific reason to build one from scratch

Comment: SUggest me one.. windows media player doesn't support snapshot option.

Answer (score 3):

its not easy to make pure video player in c#, btw you have to you use c++ libraries, anyway best is to find a library, vlc has some dll to inject it in your c# application. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382793/does-vlc-media-player-have-a-c-sharp-interface) is more info..
Hmm if you want just snapshot by code.. now its more different, you can use [EmguCv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for that. Its opencv wrapper for .net.

Comment: I tried this audio is only working video is not working

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/298989_10151163491912126_607550067_n.jpg

Comment: You made something wrong, i use it many times in my application.. btw you get error? or something?

Comment: you can check the photo i uploaded https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/298989_10151163491912126_607550067_n.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The best one I know for stuff like this is [DirectShow.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2615/DirectShow-NET), its quite easy to use and will allow you to take screenshots.

Comment: can you post an example? it will be of great help!

Comment: @HemPoudyal: DirectShow.NET has a lot of samples included.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using Windows Media Player Control in **WinForms** 
[Using the Windows Media Player Control with Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Embedding the Windows Media Player Control in a C# Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** For capturing a screenshot check this discussion 
[Capture frame from video](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/994554ec-219e-4090-9ddf-befd51bd4912)

Comment: do you have any idea, how to take snapshot while using windows media player control in winforms?

Comment: it wasn't for winforms..

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF MediaElement. For taking a snapshot, you can use RenderTargetBitmap to capture the current video frame from the MediaElement. See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/51a67a51-9880-40ec-9a42-38a547c5392c/).