# Play OGG, MP4 in .NET

Tags: .net, audio, codec, audio-player

I'd like to make a quick and dirty simple media player in .NET. I have no idea how I may play music, pause, etc. I want to support ogg, mp3 and if possible mp4.

How do I actually playback the sound? Min requirements: Play, pause/resume, stop supporting mp3 and ogg (vorbis)

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Are you trying to use codecs?  Access the sound card?  Or, do you not care about those details and just want to build a media player?  If the latter, I suggest using libVLC.

Comment: @Brad: Make that an answer and mention libvlcnet http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/?source=dlp and 200 rep may be yours 7 days from now

Answer (score 5):

Since you need to support a variety of codecs, I recommend libVLC.  It's what powers VLC, and can handle just about any codec and playback option you can imagine.  There are a few .NET wrappers available:

- [**Libvlc.Net**](http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/) (GPL)
- [**LibVLC.NET**](http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/) (LGPL) (Note that this is a different library than the first!)
- [**nVLC**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC) (GPL 3.0)
- [**VideoLan DotNet**](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) (MS Public License)

You could also ditch the fancy wrapper, and [call functions via straight-up imports](http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c/).  If you don't need all the abstraction, this may be the way to go.

See these related StackOverflow posts:

- [Does VLC media player have a C# interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382793/does-vlc-media-player-have-a-c-sharp-interface)

I recently had a project where I simply executed VLC in the background, receiving it's output via STDIO.  For what I was going, this was easier, as my command to VLC was fire-and-forget.

Answer (score 1):

[NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) is an excellent open-source library for .Net that you can use to play MP3 files. [NVorbis](https://github.com/NVorbis/NVorbis) can be used to play .ogg files.

Answer (score 0):

For playing ogg file you can try [oggsharp](https://github.com/knot3/OggSharp) it is written in pure C# without any external dependencies.

For MP4 you should go with [directshow](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2632/DirectShow-MediaPlayer-in-C)